# Imagemagick mogrify stopped working on Cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, imagemagick

I've been using Imagemagick's mogrify on Cygwin, but at some point it stopped working. I've tried uninstalling / reinstalling, but still no go.

When I try to run `mogrify` it trows this error :

```
/usr/bin/mogrify.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Anyone have any hints on what's causing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the cause of the problem, but compiling ImageMagick from source did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`ldd /usr/bin/mogrify` will show you which libraries the executable is linked with. One or more of them is missing, and they were probably part of another package which you uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've checked with ldd and all the linked libraries listed are still there...

Answer (score 1):

try this command

```
cygcheck mogrify
```

then you'll find that your missing a "cygXdmcp-6.dll"

go find it, and this problem should be solved!

good luck~

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, I have already fixed the problem by compiling ImageMagick from source...so I can't say that that was the problem with my ImageMagick installation.